# ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled while encrypting the connection string of the Web.config file

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I tried to encrypt the connection string section of the web.config file via a simple winforms application. I ran the VS2010 as an administrator and ran the following section of code.

```
 private void encryptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Configuration config = GetConfiguration();
            ConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            if (configSection != null)
                // Only encrypt the section if it is not already protected
                if (!configSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
                {
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(
                        "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                    config.Save();
                    DisplayWebConfig();
                }
        }

private Configuration GetConfiguration() 
        {
            var configFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC");
            var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName,true,configFile.Name);
            var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
            wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/",vdm);
            return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
        }
```

I tried to open the file from a physical path location and write back the encrypted info into it. But config.Save() threw me the below error.

```
ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled.

Unable to save config to file 'C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC'.
```

Stacktrace looks like below :

```
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.ReplaceFile(String Source, String Target)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.WriteFileContext.Complete(String filename, Boolean success)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticWriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.WriteCompleted(String streamName, Boolean success, Object writeContext)
   at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.SaveAs(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceUpdateAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.SaveAsImpl(String filename, ConfigurationSaveMode saveMode, Boolean forceSaveAll)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration.Save()
   at EncryptionandDecryptionApplication.Form1.encryptButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\Form1.cs:line 55
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at EncryptionandDecryptionApplication.Program.Main() in C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\EncryptionandDecryptionApplication\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: @"C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC" is not a file path.  It is a directory path.  try...@"C:\Users\abalawan\Desktop\CN\R13 new\Websites\ABC\web.config"

Comment: Thanks a ton :)
Solved my problem at last :)